# Rails 3 - paperclip image rotation?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I'm trying to use paperclip for image rotation and I found this gist on github that do the job

https://gist.github.com/827760

unfortunately it doesn't work well and always gives me this ERR :

undefined method `rotation' for #

any ideas how can I fix it ?

PS: I'm very new to rails and ruby in general

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try replacing self.rotation with self.rotation_degrees